# Send large data OkHttp3 outofmemory

Tags: android, xml, post, okhttp

I want to send a PDF image to the server in Android.

The server spec needs I should use Base64 encoding.

So I should convert the PDF Image file to Base64 String.

Below is the HTTP POST request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
    <auth>
        <!-- auth info -->
    </auth>
    <imagefile>
        <filename>Test Attachment</filename>
        <type>pdf</type>
        <data>"HERE IS BASE64 String"</data>
    </imagefile>
</request>
```

And I used below code, it is just Http post request code.

```
fun post(url: String, xml: String) = Observable.defer {
    val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(RequestBody.create(contentType, xml))
            .build()

    okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute()
}
```

In case of the small pdf file, it's ok. (Works fine)

But when I used the large pdf file(over 20MB), out of memory occurs.

So I tried another way like below.

```
fun post(url: String, xmlFile: File) = Observable.defer {
    val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(RequestBody.create(contentType, xmlFile))
            .build()

    okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute()
}
```

The difference is that I don't use String, but File.

I created a file using the Base64 encoded text with XML syntax.

But it is failed too.

How can I send the large data in Android without OOM?

Answer (score 3):

You're going to need to find a streaming base64 encoder and use that to write a RequestBody that streams to the server. There is no such encoder built-in to OkHttp or Okio but you can use the one in Android itself. Use wrap on the OutputStream that you'll get in the writeTo method of your custom RequestBody.

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Base64.Encoder